# How can I put JSON data into CoffeeScript?

Tags: json, coffeescript

Specifically, if I have some json:

```
var myData = [ 'some info', 'some more info' ]
var myOtherData = { someInfo: 'some more info' }
```

What's the correct `CoffeeScript` syntax for that?

Comment: Right, you have to decide whether `myData` is a key-value hash or an array. Whether you're in JSON, JavaScript, or CoffeeScript, `{}` denotes an "object literal" (a set of key-value pairs) and `[]` denotes an "array literal" (an ordered list).

Comment: @Shamoon you probably got a downvote because you didn't put valid json data in to your question.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you want to create an array you can use `myData = ['some info', 'some more info']`

If you want to create an object you can use `myData = {someKey: 'some value'}`

Or you can use just `myData = someKey: 'some value'` (i.e. you can omit the `{}`)

For more complicated object structures you use indentation with optional `{}` and optional commas, for example

```
myData =
    a: "a string"
    b: 0
    c:
        d: [1,2,3]
        e: ["another", "array"]
    f: false
```

will result in the variable myData containing an object with the following JSON representation, (which also happens to be valid CoffeeScript):

```
{
  "a": "a string",
  "b": 0,
  "c": {
    "d": [1, 2, 3],
    "e": ["another", "array"]
  },
  "f": false
}
```

Comment: Good overview. Just to clarify, almost all JSON or JavaScript object/array literals will work just fine when copy+pasted into CoffeeScript.